# How to call gallery.phtml file in my custom phtml?

Tags: magento2, phtml

I have created a custom widget and now, I am trying to display product images [image]

Something like in the Product view page.

On `catalog_product_view.xml` it calls `/vagrant/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

How can I call gallery.phtml in my custom phtml file?

Comment: You could try embedding it with PHP?:
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::gallery.phtml")->toHtml() ?>

You will probably have to create an override for the file in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.php and call it from there

Comment: and how can I pass the variable (the product id)? could you please give me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edit your catalog_product_view.xml file, move the media gallery block to your custom block

```
<move element="product.info.media" destination="your_block_name" as="product.info.media" />
```

After that you can call media gallery block to your custom phtml file like below

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('product.info.media') ?>
```